# Scala inferring wrong type when using Seq append operator "+:"

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm still pretty new to Scala.  I'm having trouble trying to append two Sequences together because the compiler is complaining about the type of the Seq.  I would like to start with a Seq[String] var and replace it with the addition of two Seq[String]'s.  In the REPL session below, we see that y :+ x is a Seq[Object], but why?

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_71).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val x = Seq[String]("a")
x: Seq[String] = List(a)

scala> var y = Seq[String]("b")
y: Seq[String] = List(b)

scala> y = y :+ x
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[Object]
 required: Seq[String]
       y = y :+ x
             ^

scala> val z = y :+ x
z: Seq[Object] = List(b, List(a))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the `:+` operator expects a single item, not a sequence. So what you're trying to do is comparable to `var y:List[String] = List("b", List("a"))`, which isn't valid. You can see this in [the documentation of Seq](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Seq@:+%28elem:A%29:Seq[A]), which shows the type of `:+` to be `A => Seq[A]`.

I think you probably want to use the `++` operator instead.

Comment: I should have known.  I was looking at [The sequence traits Seq, IndexedSeq, and LinearSeq](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_5.html) which says `x +: xs`  `A new sequence that consists of x prepended to xs.` Since it didn't mention types I thought `:+` must be ok.